# Node reverse proxy HTTP to HTTPS redirects

Tags: node.js, https, reverse-proxy

I have a simple reverse proxy with node-http-proxy that I want to use to just forward REST requests from my front-end.

It works fine as long as the target is http, but when the target is https node crashes! (My server is not https)

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.all("/*", function(req, res) {
  let server = 'https://www.example.com'; // forward requests to this address

  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: server});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Proxy running on port 3000');
});
```

> Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host:
>   localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.example.com,
>   DNS:example.com"

Can I get http to https requests to work with node-http-proxy in this way without changing any CORS parameters on the target server?

Comment: Honestly this isn't something you should bother trying to code. Nginx works very well for acting as an SSL termination point and for handling URL redirect from http to https. Let it's do it's job and focus your app on the special stuff it needs to do.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can I do this without a SSL certificate for my server?

Comment: If you want https, you need an SSL cert. If you're using nginx, you would have all traffic except localhost go to nginx, which handles the SSL termination and then reverse proxies to your node app. The node app would listen on http (some port that isn't available except to nginx) or on a Unix socket.

Comment: Can't I use nginx to proxy my requests and based on if it's http or https it will forward the traffic as http or https? I want to be able to specify either or on my front-end so it has to be dynamic in some sense.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well, but generally you don't.  Generally, you terminate the SSL on NGINX, and that way your upstream apps (e.g. the node app) don't have to know or care about SSL.  You configure the firewalls to make sure that the only access to them is through the NGINX frontend.